# Помогите сложить инпуты...!

Tags: javascript

Результат первого суммирования input 1 и 2 запишется в input result. Input 1 и 2 после клика на кнопку обнулятся. Как суммировать значение в input result с новыми значениями 1 и 2 input?

```html
<input id="one" type="number" placeholder="значение 1">
<input id="two" type="number" placeholder="значение 2">

<button id="button">Click</button>
<input id="result" type="number" placeholder="результат">
```

JS:

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  result.value += Number(one.value) + Number(two.value);
  one.value = 0;
  two.value = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто пытаетесь складывать строку в `result.value` с числом.

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  result.value = Number(result.value || 0) + Number(one.value) + Number(two.value);
  one.value = 0;
  two.value = 0;
};
```

```html
<input id="one" type="number" placeholder="значение 1">
<input id="two" type="number" placeholder="значение 2">

<button id="button">Click</button>
<input id="result" type="number" placeholder="результат">
```